# Perl - Comparison of Files using specific substrings

Tags: perl, file, compare, substring

i ve writted thsi script to compare lines of two files, and output common/not common lines into two different files. The script is :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $f1 = shift || "CSP8216.TXT";                                            
my $f2 = shift || "CSP8217.TXT";                                            

open my $fh1, '>', 'file1';
open FH2, '>', 'file2';

my %results;

open my $file1, '<', $f1;                                                   
while (my $line = <$file1>) { 
$results{$line} = 1  
}                           

open my $file2, '<', $f2;                                                   
while (my $line = <$file2>) {
   $results{$line}++ 
}                           

foreach my $line (sort { $results{$b} <=> $results{$a} } keys %results) 
{   
    if ($results{$line} >= 1)
    {
    print {$fh1} "$line";
    }
   else 
   {
   print FH2 "$line";
   }
}
```

My problem is when i try to mod this script but run the comparisons based on specific substrings of each line, ie :

- If a specific substring of a line of file A matches another specific     substring of a line in File B, then output said /entire/ line of File B into fh1, otherwise output it into fh2.

I tried this, but it doesnt work - really new to Perl still, any help will be really appreciated :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $f1 = shift || "CSP8216.TXT";                                            
my $f2 = shift || "CSP8216.TXT";                                            

open my $fh1, '>', 'file1';
open FH2, '>', 'file2';

my %results;

open my $file1, '<', $f1;                                                   
while (my $line = <$file1>) 
{
    my $sbs1 = substr($line, 0, 10); 
    $results{$sbs1} = 1 
}                           

open my $file2, '<', $f2;                                                   
while (my $line = <$file2>) 
{
    my $sbs2 = substr($line, 0, 10);
    $results{$sbs2}++ 
}                           

foreach my $line (sort { $results{$b} <=> $results{$a} } keys %results) 
{   
    if ($results{$line} >= 1)
    {
    print {$fh1} "$line";
    }
    else 
    {
    print FH2 "$line";
    }
}
```

This does not work, and i have a feeling its a problem in the logic, it outputs just the substrings in a single line.

Comment: Your code does not work as intended if the same content appears twice in either file A or file B. The solution is to use separate hashes for each file and then check that a line exists in both hashes.

Comment: `$results{$line} >= 1` should be `$results{$line} > 1`, otherwise(according to code) all lines are same in both files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, we need to keep the lines from file A and file B separate if we need to support that a single line can appear twice in one file.

On option is to solve the basic problem like this

```
open my $fh1, '<', $filename1 or die "Can't open $file1: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh1>) {
    $combined{$line} = $file1{$line} = 1;
}

open my $fh2, '<', $filename2 or die "Can't open $file2: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh2>) {
    $combined{$line} = $file2{$line} = 1;
}

open my $out1, '>', $outfilename1 or die "...";
open my $out2, '>', $outfilename2 or die "...";

for my $line (keys %combined) {
    if ($file1{$line} && $file2{$line}) {
        print $out1 $line;
    } else {
        print $out2 $line;
    }
}
```

To solve the substring issue I would keep the substrings from each file as keys in the hashes. But instead of just storing the true value I would store the full string as value in %file2:

```
open my $fh1, '<', $filename1 or die "Can't open $file1: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh1>) {
    my $substr = substr($line, 0, 10);
    $combined{$line} = $file1{$substr} = 1;
}

open my $fh2, '<', $filename2 or die "Can't open $file2: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh2>) {
    my $substr = substr($line, 20, 30);
    $combined{$line} = 1;
    $file2{$substr} = $line;
}

open my $out1, '>', $outfilename1 or die "...";
open my $out2, '>', $outfilename2 or die "...";

for my $line (keys %combined) {
    my $substr1 = substr($line, 0, 10);
    my $substr2 = substr($line, 20, 30);
    if ($file1{$substr1} && $file2{$substr2}) {
        print $out1 $file2{$substr2};
    } else {
        print $out2 $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried a different version of the code, can i just edit my original post or try a new one?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use autodie;

my %results;

my $f1 = shift || "CSP8216.TXT";
my $f2 = shift || "CSP8217.TXT";

open my $fh1, '>', 'file1';
open my $fh2, '>', 'file2';


open my $file1, '<', $f1;
while (my $line = <$file1>) {
    my $sbs1 = substr($line, 0, 10);
    $results{$sbs1} = 1
}

open my $file2, '<', $f2;
while (my $line = <$file2>) {
    my $sbs2 = substr($line, 0, 10);
    if (!$results{$sbs2}) {
        $results{$sbs2} = 1;
    }
    $results{$sbs2}++
}

foreach my $line (sort { $results{$b} <=> $results{$a} } keys %results) {
    if ($results{$line} > 1) {
        print {$fh1} "$line";
    }
    else {
        print {$fh2} "$line";
    }
}
```